# Inline assembly : register referencing conventions

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86

In gcc inline assembly examples found on the net, I see register names being referenced sometimes with a single `%` and other times with two (i.e. `%%`). It's not clear when to use
a single `%` and when to use `%%`.
e.g. please see below example.

```
/* Do b = a */

  int a=10, b;

  asm ("movl %1, %%eax;\n"
       "movl %%eax, %0;"
       : "=r" (b)        /* output */
       : "r" (a)         /* input */
       : "%eax"          /* clobbered register */
       );
```

This example which uses `%%` prefix for `EAX` register compiles fine on my x86 machine (Linux RedHat 5.6(Tikanga 2.6.18-238.5.1.el5 x86_64, kernel 2.6.18, gcc 4.7.2). But the following single line code

```
asm ("movl %%ecx, %%eax");
```

produces the error below.

```
a.c: Assembler messages:

a.c:14: Error: bad register name `%%ecx'
```

Could someone please throw some light on when to use `%` and when to use `%%` ?

Thank you.

Comment: You should definitely read http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html

Comment: `asm ("movl %ecx, %eax");` is the right syntax for Basic asm, but it can't safely be used anywhere; that would destroy EAX without telling the compiler.  https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/ConvertBasicAsmToExtended

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the main body of the `asm` (ie. the part where the actual code goes), you use `%1`, `%2`, etc. to refer to the arguments to the inline-asm block.  The inline-asm treats `%` as a special character for this purpose.

It so happens that the GNU assembler syntax for x86 *also* uses `%` as a prefix for the x86 register names (`%eax`, `%ebx`, etc.).  But, because the inline-asm assigns different meaning to `%`, you have to double up the `%` in that block to escape it.  That's why you see `movl %1, %%eax`:  The first `%1` expands to an argument, the `%%` in front of `%%eax` gets replaced with a single `%`, resulting in `%eax` in the final assembly output by the compiler.

In the other strings after the code block, `%` doesn't have this special meaning any more.  That's why in the clobber list, for example, you only need to say `%eax`.

In your second example, the inline assembler has no arguments.  There are no `%1`... substitution specifiers, and so  you don't need to double up the `%`.

Clear as mud?

Comment: Thanks Joe Z, Rob Starling and elyashiv. I did read the page mentioned by Rob Starling, but it doesn't explain this % Vs %% difference as well as explained by Joe Z. After reading Joe Z's explanation, now it's very clear. Thanks again Joe Z.

Comment: @user3017124 Please consider accepting the answer. Here at Stackoverflow we don't say thank you; we accept and upvote answers instead.